# Proving a certain set is inductive

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's give some context. We have to prove «Krull's theorem», which states that:

> If $A$ is a commutative ring, $N$ is its (nil)radical, i.e. the set of its nilpotent elements $\{x\in A:\exists p\in\mathbb{N}:x^p=0\}$, and $N_0$ is the intersection of all its prime ideals, then:
>   $$N=N_0.$$

We prove it by proving $N\subseteq N_0$ and $N_0\subseteq N$. For the second one we prove $A\smallsetminus N_0\subseteq A\smallsetminus N$, i.e. that $x\not\in N_0\implies x\not\in N$. The proof starts by setting $S=\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ and seeing it is a multiplicative submonoid of $(A,\cdot)$. Since $x^p\neq0\forall p\in\mathbb{N}$, we deduce that $\{0\}\cap S=\varnothing$. That means that:
$$\Pi=\{I\leq A:I\cap S=\varnothing\}\neq\varnothing,$$
where by $\leq$ I denote "is an ideal of". Then we state $\Pi$ is inductive, and thus by Zorn's lemma has a maximal element $J$. The proof then moves on to proving $J$ is prime, which concludes our proof, since $x\not\in J$. We have the following definition of "inductive":

> A set of sets where each ascending chain has a supremum (i.e. a maximal element) is inductive.

So the question is: how do I prove this $\Pi$ is inductive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P \subseteq \Pi$ is a chain, then $\cup P$ is an upper bound.

Comment: Trouble is, my definition of inductive failed to specify the upper bound should be in the set of sets. And since $\Pi$ is a collection of ideals, I would need to prove the upper bound is an ideal. But that is in fact easy: 0 is in that upper bound as it is in each ideal; if $x,y$ are in the bound, let's call the bound $B$, then they are in at least one ideal, so there are $I_x,I_y$ such that $x\in I_x,y\in I_y$, and evidently one of them contains the other, thus one of them contains $x,y$ and thus their difference; if $x$ is in $B$, it's in one ideal, just like $ax$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: Yes this works.

Comment: And naturally the bound $B$, which we have just proved to be an ideal, has an empty intersection with $S$, and as such is in $\Pi$. OK I admit I should have thought a bit more before asking the question :).

Comment: It's just that I've never really done much set theory, so I didn't manage to come up with the union as a possible upper bound.